# Is it possible to add a custom parameter in a Open Graph story with a common action?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We're working on a fitness application where people run and carry out a physical activity for the community as part of a workout.

For example, on Wednesday, Axel ran 5.6km and helped dig a wild flower garden.

We want to build an easy way for users to share these stories on their timelines in Facebook with a map of the course they ran and a sentance that describes the activity.  We've opted to use the `fitness.runs` common action and can provide the `course` information easily enough, however it's not clear if or how we can add a custom parameter `task` in the sentence.  Ideally the story (with accompanied map) would read:

```
*Axel* ran *5.6* km to *help dig a wild flower garden* with GoodGym.
```

Any advice on how to get that working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. Looking at both the run action and the course object you cannot add custom properties.  For example, when you go to configure the run action you see the following message at the top "Common Action Type: Run You are viewing the configuration options for the common Action Type: Run. These are read only and are displayed for informational purposes only."

However you might want to consider using User Messages which "allow users to write a personalized message attached to this action." Then you could encourage users to write something about what they helped to do.